# How to create column with two divs one fixed above second that hides behind first when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to create container sticking to navbar with the same width like parent column in responsive design? When link in first div was clicked then content div will be scrolled to right height so that content hides behind `hr` and links div. All this in one column.

I've created starting template [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smUx8/3/)

My desired effect:
[image: mockup]

Current bad HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <form class="navbar-search pull-right">
                <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span9">
                <div class="hidebehind">
                    <div class="push">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="well links">
                                <div class="span3">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#scroll1" rel="" id="scroll2" class="scroll">scroll to 1</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#scroll2" rel="" id="scroll2" class="scroll">scroll to 2</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#scroll3" rel="" id="scroll3" class="scroll">scroll to 3</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#scroll4" rel="" id="scroll4" class="scroll">scroll to 4</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="span3">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#scroll5" rel="" id="scroll5" class="scroll">scroll to 5</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="row scrollable">
                    <div class="well">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a name="scroll1" id="scroll1to"><strong>1. Some text</strong></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a name="scroll2" id="scroll2to"><strong>2. Some text</strong></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a name="scroll3" id="scroll3to"><strong>3. Some text</strong></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a name="scroll4" id="scroll4to"><strong>4. Some text</strong></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a name="scroll5" id="scroll5to"><strong>5. Some text</strong></a>
                        </li></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="well">relative</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="well">footer</div>
</div>
```

Current bad CSS:

```
.links {
    width:58%;
    position:fixed;
}
.hidebehind {
    position: fixed;
    width:58%;
}
.scrollable {
    margin-top:170px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Use `position: fixed;`?

Comment: But when I'm useing fixed then links conteiner isn't sticking to column and main content starting position isn't in right row.

Comment: Fix that using additional CSS. Give it a sufficiently high top margin. `position: fixed` (like `position: absolute`) removes elements from the flow layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED:

http://jsfiddle.net/smUx8/4/

All you need is some `position: fixed` and a `margin-top`

Comment: Thanks. But how to hide content behind links row?

Comment: This is not consistent to the end with my concept. If is it possible How to make one column with first row containing links fixed and second row with content which hides completely behind first row and not showing itself above it?

Comment: Sorry but I did not understood that one.

Comment: I presented what I mean on the mockup. Maybe in approach presented in my html template it is not possible. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to use `overflow:auto` on .scrollable and wrap it in some container, with `overflow: hidden` and size smaller, than the size of the .scrollable. This will make the content of the .scrollable be... scrollable =) and no scrollbars will be seen.

In this method we animate not the root html|body, but the content block itself, and add `position:relative` to it, so that its contents' position properties don't mess every time the div is scrolled.

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tBE62/8/)